# graphing bar graphs and error bars with R

Tags: r

I have a csv file with two columns and I am trying to graph it with error bars.

```
a,b
1207,1457
2520,1207
1328,1136
1393,1112
8984,7680...
```

However my following code doesn't work:

```
> data.means<-lapply(data, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
> data.sd <- lapply(data,sd)
> x = barplot(data.means, ylim=c(0,10000))
*Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator*
> error.bar(barx,data.means, 1.96*data.sd/10)
```

Comment: can anyone confirm that `1.96*data.sd/10` is the correct formula?

Answer (score 0):

Use sapply instead of lapply. lapply creates a list, but barplot takes a vector or matrix.

```
data.sd <- sapply(data,sd)

x = barplot(data.means, ylim=c(0,10000))
```